# Substract values in two columns: cannot get negative values

Tags: r

I need to substract the values in two columns. The following codes are the example data and how I do it. I realized that the negative values are all turned into NAs with this warning message: `Warning message: In eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : NAs introduced by coercion`. May I ask how can I also get the negative values?

**Sample data**

```
structure(list(BASELINE = c("475238,095", "700000"), MAXV = c(4630000L, 
3620000L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001b01ba11ef0>)
```

**How I do it**

```
data [,ST:= as.numeric(MAXV) - as.numeric(BASELINE)]
```

[image]

Comment: It has nothing to do with negative values. Try `as.numeric("475238,095")`. If the `,` is used as decimal point, you may change `dec` in `read.table` / `fread`. Then the values should be read as numeric.

Comment: @Henrik You're right. I already got `NA` with `as.numeric("475238,095")`.  May I ask if this is what I should do? Initial codes: `data_startle <- rbindlist(lapply(setNames(mydata1,paste0('subject',1:40)), fread),idcol='subject')` --- New codes: `data_startle <- rbindlist(lapply(setNames(mydata1,paste0('subject',1:40)), fread(dec = ',')),idcol='subject')`

Comment: In `lapply`, you may use the `...`, optional arguments to `FUN`, where in your case `FUN` is `fread`, and the optional argument is `dec` there. Thus, `lapply(x, fread, dec = ",")`

Answer (score 0):

As @Henrik's answer in the comment above. The problem is not the negative values but the data structure.

Because the `,` is used as decimal point, I need to change `dec` in `fread` function.

**My initial codes to load data is as follows:**

```
data_startle <- rbindlist(lapply(setNames(mydata1,paste0('subject',1:40)), fread),idcol='subject')
```

**Correct one:**

```
data_startle <- rbindlist(lapply(setNames(mydata1,paste0('subject',1:40)), fread),idcol='subject', dec = ","))
```